# What settings are needed in Xcode to get this code to build

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

Let's take this code, which is in a header file. The project itself is Objective-C++ (.h & .mm files).

This looks like a mix of C++ and Objective-C. From what I've read, in order to mix Objective-C++ with Objective-C you have to keep all C++ stuff out of the header file, however this is not the case.

The project builds fine, however I cannot replicate this in a new project (by copying the same code).

What settings are needed in Xcode to get this to build? Already compared the project build settings and they're identical.

The errors are related to the inline initializers inside the `Options` struct.

```
/*
  This file is part of the Structure SDK.
  Copyright © 2019 Occipital, Inc. All rights reserved.
  http://structure.io
*/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#import <Structure/Structure.h>
#import <Structure/STCaptureSession.h>

#import "CalibrationOverlay.h"
#import "MeshViewController.h"
#import "SettingsPopupView.h"

// See default initialization in: -(void)initializeDynamicOptions
struct DynamicOptions
{
    bool depthAndColorTrackerIsOn;
    bool improvedTrackingIsOn;
    bool highResColoring;
    bool improvedMapperIsOn;
    bool highResMapping;
    STCaptureSessionPreset depthStreamPreset;
};

struct Options
{
    // The initial scanning volume size will be 0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5 meters
    // (X is left-right, Y is up-down, Z is forward-back)
    const GLKVector3 initVolumeSizeInMeters = GLKVector3Make (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    
    // The maximum number of keyframes saved in keyFrameManager
    int maxNumKeyFrames = 48;
    
    // Colorizer quality
    STColorizerQuality colorizerQuality = STColorizerHighQuality;
    
    // Take a new keyframe in the rotation difference is higher than 20 degrees.
    float maxKeyFrameRotation = 20.0f * (M_PI / 180.f); // 20 degrees
    
    // Take a new keyframe if the translation difference is higher than 30 cm.
    float maxKeyFrameTranslation = 0.3; // 30cm

    // Threshold to consider that the rotation motion was small enough for a frame to be accepted
    // as a keyframe. This avoids capturing keyframes with strong motion blur / rolling shutter.
    float maxKeyframeRotationSpeedInDegreesPerSecond = 1.f;
    
    // Whether we should use depth aligned to the color viewpoint when Structure Sensor was calibrated.
    // This setting may get overwritten to false if no color camera can be used.
    bool useHardwareRegisteredDepth = false;
    
    // Whether to enable an expensive per-frame depth accuracy refinement.
    // Note: this option requires useHardwareRegisteredDepth to be set to false.
    const bool applyExpensiveCorrectionToDepth = true;
    
    // Whether the colorizer should try harder to preserve appearance of the first keyframe.
    // Recommended for face scans.
    bool prioritizeFirstFrameColor = true;
    
    // Target number of faces of the final textured mesh.
    int colorizerTargetNumFaces = 50000;
    
    // Focus position for the color camera (between 0 and 1). Must remain fixed one depth streaming
    // has started when using hardware registered depth.
    const float lensPosition = 0.75f;
};

...
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <STBackgroundTaskDelegate, MeshViewDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, SettingsPopupViewDelegate>
{
...
}
@end
```

Some details about the errors as well:

[image]

Comment: anything outside the `@interface .. @end` and `@implementation .. @end` statements is in fact plain C or C++, so here it is C++ then.

Comment: @OlSen That's interesting. But it's still not explaining why it doesn't build in a new project.

Comment: hint: in old times we used .hh to tell Xcode that the file is a C++ or ObjC++ header.
And in my other answer to your Options struct compile problem you see that i defined what language ruleset is enclosing the code with the #ifdef statements

Comment: what helps a lot usually is to let Xcode setup the header-file for you so your statements to make clear what language ruleset is used is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are only `#include`/`#import`ing this header from `.mm` files.

The default struct field values are a new feature of C++11. Is the C++ standard in the new project perhaps set to C++98?

I'm not 100% sure on the details, but perhaps some of the more complex default value expressions are only possible in an even newer version of C++. So I suggest you try changing the C++ standard version in the project and see whether it has any effect.

[image: C++ language dialect setting in Xcode]

Comment: Thanks! The C++ standard was set to GNU 11. Now it's 17 but the same errors. Also, the same code compiles in another Xcode project, on the same machine. Settings are seemingly the same.

Comment: Added it in the OP. It's the first error for each occurrence. The missing types can be ignored, I think.

Comment: I don’t think they can be ignored. Are you sure this file isn’t included (even indirectly) from a .m file? The screenshot isn’t great as it doesn’t include the error back trace. Copy-paste from the build log is much more helpful.

Comment: Solved it finally. It was about the C++ and C (GNU11) standards set in the project. It worked after a clean & Xcode restart (not sure if the restart is really needed). Also, in the file inspector I made sure to set the `.mm` file type to Objective-C++ source.